# is there a firefox fork with v8 engine instead of spidermonkey?

Tags: firefox, browser

Firefox engine is a bit slow compared to chromium's,

[brave(chrome based) overall score](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQyMT.png)

[Firefox overall score](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rPek.png)

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't. Firefox have no reason to want to use V8, and I don't think that would be an easy feat to replace the SpiderMonkey engine.

Comment: The question is off topic. Do not answer off topic questions. [answer] Vote to close them instead.